# flowtype bind cause error `Convariant property incompatible with contravariant use in assignment of property`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

This expression is very simple for javascript / react, to bind function with `this` scope.

```js
this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
```

But when introduce with **flowtype**, that cause error:

[image]

What can I do to pass flow test?

toggle can be any function even empty.

```js
toggle() {
    /// do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare your `toggle` as `Function` in your class like this (compact way):

```
class Foo {

    toggle: Function = () {
        ...
    }

}
```

or, you can separate the signature and the actual method:

```
class Foo {

    toggle: Function;

    toggle() {
        ...
    }

}
```

or, as you say

See [this issue](https://github.com/ryyppy/flow-guide/issues/6) for more details

Comment: I didn't notice that is not declared, although  I read the  resolved issue

Comment: @AdrienLacroix Your answer is really enlightening, thanks again. I found another 3 ways to achieve this, that might helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45857984/681830

Comment: @Val, I didn't know the fourth one, this is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Now I know 4 ways to achieve this.

I knew 1) and 2) before asking the question, but I think that's ugly personally.

Thanks to [Adrien Lacroix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355701/adrien-lacroix)'s solution (of number 3), and lead a way to which I favor the most (number 4).

### 1. Cast `this` as `any`

Reference to [flowtype issue #1517](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1517).

```js
(this: any).toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
```

### 2. Assign to another variable of `any`

Set `this` to another variable which is `any` type. Same as 1) but with many functions to bind, it's a handy way to avoid casting every line.

```js
const self: any = this;
self.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
```

### 3. define function type clearly

```js
toggle: Function;
toggle() {
    ...
}
```

### 4. define function with type + arrow function

```js
toggle: Function = () => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, toggle needs separate declaration, like as below (not sure of use of it as not provided code)

```
toggle: Function;

toggle() {
    console.log('ho');
}
```

You can check these reference links for the same:

https://github.com/ryyppy/flow-guide/issues/6

and

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3076

**EDIT**

From the [official document](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/) you need to do like this to avoid error:

> Convariant property incompatible with contravariant use in assignment
>   of property

```
function g(o: {-p: string}): void {
  o.p = "default";
}
var o: {p: ?string} = {p: null};
g(o);
```

Comment: toggle can be an empty function. modified my answer.

Comment: it actually works as valid javascript expression, just didn't pass flow test.

Comment: No. if that's the case it would be a javascript error. that's not the case.

Comment: This worked for me but didn't fix the issue I was trying to solve which was that Webstorm kept complaining about `duplicate declaration for toggle`.